# PHPStan misses interface implementation when inferring return type

Tags: php, static-analysis, abstraction, phpstan

I recently started playing with PHPStan, and encountered a roadblock that I just cannot get past. Some visual aid might make this easier for me to explain. Class names are simplified to keep things easy to read:

We have two interfaces: `Enumerable` and `LeadContract`. Then, we have another interface (`LeadRepository`) that features a method with this signature:

- `public function list(): Enumerable<int, LeadContract>;`

The problem comes from the implementation we did of `LeadRepository`. In this implementation, we have a `list` method that returns `Collection<int, LeadModel>`, PHP gives us no problem with this, but PHPStan does.

What we've noticed is that PHPStan currently seems to:

- Expect `Enumerable<int, LeadContract>`
- But gets `Collection<int, LeadModel>`

Now, `Collection` implements `Enumerable`, and `LeadModel` implements `LeadContract`. I am just having a tough time figuring out why PHPStan continues to complain about it, even though we are implementing our interfaces in all the correct classes.

We tried to use generics, but then PHPStan would complain about us not using them in a parameter. We used them in the return type, but that didn't seem to satisfy that rule.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Please reproduce the problem on phpstan.org/try so that it’s clear what’s going on.Also - you’re much more likely to get a useful answer in PHPStan’s GitHub Discussions.

Comment: And feel free to attach the version with generics too - should work like a breeze.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I reproduced the problem using the link you provided: https://phpstan.org/r/9a812be8-9917-45a0-9327-88d9183a5121

Comment: Thank you for the GitHub discussions suggestion, just to make sure, it's `phpstan/phpstan`?

Answer (score 0):

After some sleep and looking through some examples, I fixed the issue by making the `LeadRepository` contract generic, and then specifying the `Lead` implementation as the generic parameter at the implementation level.

Example:

```php
/**
 * @template T of LeadContract
 */
interface LeadRepository
{
    /**
     * @return Enumerable<int, T>
     */
    public function findByPhoneNumber(string $phoneNumber): Enumerable;
}
```

```php
/**
 * @implements LeadRepositoryContract<Lead>
 */
class LeadRepository implements LeadRepositoryContract
{
    {...}

    public function findByPhoneNumber(string $phoneNumber): Enumerable
    {
        return Lead::where([
            'phone_number' => $phoneNumber,
        ])->get();
    }
}
```

I used TypeScript as a basis for how PHPStan worked, and assumed it would infer the generic parameter from the function signature. Now I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Thank you @Ondrej! I think I needed to see the problem reproduced differently to figure out the solution.